# Getting linter error "Unexpected token =" with destructuring assignment on previously declared variables

Tags: javascript, eslint

```
let data = []
let count, meta
if (req.params.id === 'count') {
  // get count only
} else {
  { data, count } = await myModel.find(filter, options)
  meta = { count }
}
```

gives me a linter error: "Parsing error: Unexpected token =" at the destructuring assignment. Is this just a setting in the linter config I need to change?

I can get rid of the error using parenthesis, but why is this required?

```
({ data, count } = await myModel.find(filter, options))
```

Comment: Because `{` at the start of the line signifies a start of a code block. Without either a declaration or a grouping operator `()` the JS interpreter will not treat `{}` as an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any statement that begins with `{ ... }` will always be have the bracketed sequence parsed as a code block rather than as an object (including a destructuring object expression).

MDN clarifies this exact case in its [documentation on destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration):

> ```
> var a, b;
>
> ({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2});
> ```
>
> **Notes:** The parentheses `( ... )` around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`
>
> Your `( ... )` expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.